# how to add onclick event to create new element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a `label` element. I need to add `onclick` event to that...

```
function a(me) {
    var d=document.createElement("label");
    d.id=me.id;
    d.onClick="a(10)";
    d.innerHTML="welcome";
    document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

HTML:

```
<label id="1" onclick="a(this)">aa</label>
<label id="2" onclick="a(this)">bb</label>
<label id="3" onclick="a(this)">aa</label>
```

actually what happens is when i click the any of three labels in html. another label is created and displays welcome. now when i click the newly created label "welcome" it does not display anything...... that is the onclick event added to newly created label is not working ....... any suggestion.................

Comment: You're using the same ID on two elements. Only use an ID once.

Comment: @tylermwashbum using id once..........

Comment: There are two labels with the ID `1`. BTW, you should not use IDs starting with a number.

Comment: You create a new label with the same id as the one clicked. (`d.id=me.id;`) And as bazmegakapa mention, ID's should always start with a letter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to set `d.onclick=function(){a(1);};`, note that the case matters here (not "onClick").

**[Edit]**

Based on your comments and updated questions I've created a [jsFiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/maerics/LMAmK/1/) how you might turn your code into something that works.

Comment: still when i click that label after adding this property. it is not calling the function.........

Comment: @maerics. the onclick event is still not working. what may be the problem...??

Comment: @thuk: please edit your question with details about what you are trying to accomplish and what specifically happens when you run your existing code, this way others can easily see the problem.  Just a guess, the argument "me" to the function looks suspicious because it will duplicate ids, which should be unique...

Comment: @thuk You can easily create a jsFiddle on jsfiddle.net to illustrate your problem even better.

Comment: @maerics finally ur code worked for me. very thanks. i have done a silly spelling mistake.... thanks ......

Comment: @bazmegakapa finally code worked for me with maerics solutions. i have done a silly spelling mistake.... thanks for ur suggestion......

Answer (score 6):

```
d.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert(\'hello\');');
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating an attribute to a HTML tag, sometimes we have to add this:

```
yourTag.src
yourTag.src = 'http://lolxd.com/404.png'
```

But there are special attributes, and them have diferents ways for editing:

```
yourTag.classList
yourTag.className
```

And there is the `onclick` attribute, wichwe can use it like this:

```
// The first way
obj.onclick = function () { alert('lalala') }
// With the Event Listener
obj.addEventListener('click', function () { alert('lalala') }, false)
// Or, a text-render way
obj.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert(`lalala`)')
```

I recomend you the Event Listener way, but try all :D